# play framework2: get rid of the initial html page in the url

Tags: redirect, playframework, routes, playframework-2.0

I have defined the following routes file:

```
GET     /           controllers.Application.app

# web service entries...
GET     /api/users  controllers.Users.list
[...]

# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET     /*file      controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

and in my Application.app action I just redirect to index.html

```
def app = Action {
  Redirect(routes.Assets.at("index.html"))
}
```

so when I access to my application at `http://mydomain` I'm redirected to `http://mydoamin/index.html`, which then add a /#ideas to the location (it's a single web page app)

I'd like to get rid of the index.html file, and instead being redirected to `http://mydoamin/#ideas`

is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this in your routes file:

```
GET     /     controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file="index.html")
```

So you need not to touch any controller.

Comment: Yeah, you're right :-) It is so simple that I did not think about it ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Just a pointer: you can try to get the Html code from the Asset controller, and then return an Ok Result with the Html content.

For that, you may try to look at how controllers are called in the [test helpers](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/ScalaFunctionalTest), and how to get the Result and body of this call.

Roughly (not tested):

```
def app = Action {
    request => {
        val result = controllers.Assets.at("public","index.html")(request)
        val html = contentAsString(result)

        Ok(html)
    }
}
```

Comment: I got a `not found: value contentAsString`. Am I missing any import? All I got is play.api._ and import play.api.mvc._

Comment: ah yeah sorry, it comes from the play.api.test.Helpers class. But since you cannot use it in the main Play app, you have to use "result.body" instead.